# Add shared module to apache CentOS7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have practiced with my apache 2.4.6 on CentOS7 and I have tried to add shared module.
I can list my compiled modules using this command `httpd -l`. All shared modules is located in `/etc/httpd/modules`. I have read a lot about modules, for example this [proxy_module](https://serverfault.com/questions/120601/cant-start-apache-in-linux-because-of-proxy-module) or this [apache modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069/apache-how-do-i-build-individual-and-or-all-modules-as-shared-modules).
My steps were:

> `vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
>
> `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so`

Reasonable permissions:
`[root@localhost conf]# ls -la ../modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 48160 Nov 19 16:44 ../modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so`

After debugging my apache `httpd -t`I got this:

> `httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so: undefined symbol: proxy_module`

I know maybe it is a hackneyed question and I am slow in a fast lane but...What did I do wrong? How to add my shared module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to add shared module and here is explanation:

> Go to `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`
>
> Create file with `.conf` extension in which you'll put you settings for shared module: `touch proxy_module.conf`
>
> Add this to `proxy_module.conf` : `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so`
>
> Restart apache: `systemctl restart httpd`

After all this steps you can use benefits of shared module.